# Pointing namecheap.com domain name to www.ovh.co.uk server

Tags: ip, domain, hosting, nameserver, ovh

I have bought vps hosting plan-3 from ovh.com. My ip is 158.69.219.147 or server vps85119.vps.ovh.ca
I have installed my site  on ovh, but my real domain name is www.free-sample-loop.com(typo corrected) from name cheap. I have added A recod on name cheap with IP 158.69.219.147 and vps85119.vps.ovh.ca but when I visit www.free-sample-loop.com (typo corrected) it takes me to 158.69.219.147 or server vps85119.vps.ovh.ca. How can I configure to get website on real URl(www.free-sample-loop.com [typo corrected]).

Comment: How long ago did you change your DNS records? It can take over 24 hours for them to update. I usually get it in an hour or two, but it once took me over 3 days for it to settle down. The domain "free-sample-loop.com" (I'm assuming fee-sample-loop.com is a typo) reports a who.is showing DNS1.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM 216.87.155.33 & DNS2.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM 216.87.152.33 as the nameservers. Also, if you could update your post to reflect your DNS record, it may provide more insight. I don't know your experience level with them, but it can be tricky to learn!

Comment: I have updated post with the correct domain name. Yes that was typo. I have updated last night, It's been 10 Hours. I have no idea about ovh.com and I am not getting DNS options. Cloud you please give a step by step guide to accomplish. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If ovh didn't set nameservers that your vps will use, you can do two things. First is to set nameserver on your own on your vps. Second option is to create dns zone on existing nameservers that domain is using (what you've tried to do).

**What to do:**

Create dns zone for your doman on existing nameservers (name cheap ones in this case) and point that domain to your VPS IP. All records should be set as A or cname to point to new IP address. You current dns zone looks like this:

```
free-sample-loop.com. 3600 IN SOA dns1.registrar-servers.com. hostmaster.registrar-servers.com. 2016061917 43200 3600 604800 3601
free-sample-loop.com. 1799 IN NS dns1.registrar-servers.com.
free-sample-loop.com. 1799 IN NS dns2.registrar-servers.com.
free-sample-loop.com. 299 IN A 158.69.219.147
free-sample-loop.com. 1799 IN MX 15 eforward4.registrar-servers.com.
free-sample-loop.com. 1799 IN MX 10 eforward1.registrar-servers.com.
free-sample-loop.com. 1799 IN MX 20 eforward5.registrar-servers.com.
free-sample-loop.com. 1799 IN MX 10 eforward3.registrar-servers.com.
free-sample-loop.com. 1799 IN MX 10 eforward2.registrar-servers.com.
free-sample-loop.com. 1799 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:spf.efwd.registrar-servers.com ~all"
```

You should create all records that you need (add www, ftp and change mx record if you'll use mail on your ovh VPS) since you're missing those record right now.

Also, you have to set domain free-sample-loop.com on your VPS. Right now, it doesn't look that domain is set, so be sure that you have added domain and configured the web server correctly. It might be that after setting up domain, that domain will use different IP address, so you'll have to change dns zone settings, but consult ovh support in case you have issues after configuring everything.